# Google Data Studio Filter Control Case Sensitive

Tags: looker-studio

I have a dashboard built on Data Studio. The default filter control to search results is case sensitive; is there a way make the search case insensitive? For example, I would like to search for "Dog" and the way it is set up now the search has to be exactly "Dog" and not "dog" or "DOG".

I tried using community visualization for search and it works great. However, this dashboard is embedded to a website and community visualization does not work in an embedded report.

Thank you!

Comment: To which type of datasource your dashboard is connected ? For instance, I found out that the filter control case sensitive for BigQuery, and case insensitive for MySQL / Mariadb.

Answer (score 7):

While [@sargsyan-grigor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4769572/sargsyan-grigor) has posted the correct answer [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69074031/7746472), I found it hard to follow because of its brevity. Here are more extensive instructions:

1. Add Parameter: The parameter will take the search text entered

- Edit data source
- "Add a Parameter"
- Name **"Searchtext"**, Data type "text", Permitted values "Any"

2. Edit input box: The input box needs to be modified, so it takes the input and stores it into the parameter

- Edit input box
- add **"Searchtext"** created in step 1 and use it as the "Control field"
- Note that this [DOESN'T WORK](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cadvanced-filter-data-options) for "Advanced filters" (which are otherwise very similar to input boxes)

3. Create Boolean field for **Search Match**: Create field that is TRUE if the field being searched contains the search text (both in lowercase)

- Edit data source
- Add a Field
- Enter formula: CONTAINS_TEXT(LOWER(field-being-searched), LOWER(Searchtext))

4. Add filter: Filter page/graph/report

- To filter entire page, go to menu "Page" > Current page settings > Add a Filter > Create a Filter > Include **Searchmatch** TRUE.
- Note that FALSE is broken in DS since [at least 2019](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/5653621/calculated-boolean-field-problem?hl=en). That's not a problem though, just rephrase to use TRUE.

Answer (score 4):

I might be a bit late, but for everyone searching this.. I had the same issue, I created a parameter 'Searched text' and assigned it as the control filter of data studio's Input Box, then created a boolean field 'Search matches' which has the following body:

```
CONTAINS_TEXT(LOWER(field-being-searched), LOWER(Searched text))
```

then applied filter on my chart - Include - 'Search matches' - IS TRUE.

Comment: Not late at all, this worked well for me, thanks. Only note I would make is that if you have "null" values in your dimension, this will automatically filter them out. It took me a while to figure out why I was missing a lot of rows but that was it.

Comment: Hi. What do we put on "Searched text" please

Answer (score 3):

By default, a regex pattern will be treated as case sensitive. To force Data Studio to ignore the case of your regex, insert (?i) at the beginning of the expression.

For example, use (?i)email to match any all case variations of “email”.
From: https://www.clickinsight.ca/blog/tips-using-regex-data-studio

Comment: To elaborate, select Add control > Advanced filter > switch the option to "Regex" > now input `(?i).*(dog).*`. You could also do `(?i).*(dog|cat).*` to find instances of "dog" or "cat"

Answer (score 0):

You also can generate a Control with regex search like this:

```
(?i)^.*\b(word)\b.*$
```

where "word" is the term that you need search...

Answer (score 0):

For me, I did it as follows:

- In the Advanced Filter setup
- Find the Control Field
- Add a new field
- Give a suitable name
- Data Type: Text
- Formula: Lower(field-name)