# Implementing Multi-column, Case-Insensitive Search with Filter Controls in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I'm currently working on a Google Data Studio report with a data source containing 150 columns. I'm seeking guidance on implementing a multi-column search functionality where users can input a search term, and the report dynamically updates to display rows where the search term appears in specific columns.

Here are my key questions:

How can I efficiently create a search functionality for specific columns without introducing a new data source?
Is there a scalable way to implement multi-column search in Google Data Studio across a large number of columns (150 in this case)?
Additionally, how can I ensure that the search functionality is case-insensitive?
Any insights, advice, or alternative approaches would be highly valuable!

Additional Context:

**The main data source has 150 columns.
I want users to be able to search across specific columns, and the search should be case-insensitive.

I'm seeking a solution to create a fixed list of columns in Google Data Studio, where each column has a corresponding input field. Essentially, I want users to be able to input search terms for specific columns from a predefined list.

I'd appreciate any guidance, insights, or recommendations on how to implement this effectively within Google Data Studio.**

I've been exploring options to implement a multi-column search in Google Data Studio for a report with 150 columns. My current approach involves creating a new data source with a single column for search terms and blending it with the main data source using a common field. I've also added a Filter Control to allow users to input search terms.

However, I'm facing challenges in efficiently creating the search functionality for specific columns without introducing a new data source and ensuring that the search is case-insensitive.

I'm open to any suggestions, insights, or alternative approaches to achieve this. Your expertise would be highly appreciated!

Comment: the case sensitive has part of your quest has been answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923621/google-data-studio-filter-control-case-sensitive

Comment: Not worked for me as good solution as I have 150 columns to search.

Comment: can you flatten your files so there is only one column to search?

Comment: flatten files having 150 columns and having more than 50K rows, will be more difficult.